# Jmeter ServerAgent cannot run, some problem of log4j

Tags: java, jmeter, log4j, jmeter-plugins

- windows10
- jmeter5.4.3
- Server Agent2.2.3

1. When I use .\startAgent.bat, there will be:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker).log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

2. Then, when I run a project in jmeter:

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=123956, tid=15320
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (11.0.13+10) (build 11.0.13+10-LTS-370)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (11.0.13+10-LTS-370, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]
    #
    # No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # D:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\ServerAgent-2.2.3\hs_err_pid123956.log
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a [SIGAR bug](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/issues/141)

Download this [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll](https://github.com/cnstar9988/sigar/raw/master/sigar-amd64-winnt.dll) and replace the one in the "lib" folder of the ServerAgent installation and it should resolve your issue.

Also be aware of the [SSHMon Samples Collector](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon), it doesn't require installation of the agent on the system under test, given there is [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) connectivity between JMeter machine and the system under test it will collect metrics in the "client" mode.

More information: [How to Monitor Server Resource Utilization with JMeter’s SSHMon Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Due to a problem with the region, I can't open your dll file link. I downloaded and changed the file separately, but it didn't worked. Because I'm using Windows, I can't use another method, but I'm thankful. My English is not very good, so I use the machine flip, I hope to forgive.